# Powershell - add results when 2 fields match

Tags: powershell

I have an input with data like this:

```
Type    Site     Count
======================
Copper  Site1    10
Copper  Site1    7
Bronze  Site1    3
Bronze  Site1    9
Copper  Site2    32
Copper  Site2    1
Bronze  Site2    3
Bronze  Site2    13
```

What i would like to have output is this

```
Type    Site     Count
======================
Copper  Site1    17
Bronze  Site1    12
Copper  Site2    33
Bronze  Site2    16
```

I have the following code:

```
Function getIndex($location)
{
  for($j = 0; $j -lt $result.Count; $j++) {
    if($result[$j].Location -contains "$location") {
      $index=$j
      break;
    }
  }
  return $index
}

for ($i=0; $i -lt $outarray.length; $i++) {
  $loc=$outarray[$i].Location
  $pcount=$outarray[$i].'Count'
  $ltype=$outarray[$i].'License Type'
  if(!($result | where-object {$_.Location -eq "$loc"})) {
    $result+=New-object psobject -property @{'Location' = $loc; 'Count' = $pcount; 'License Type' = $ltype}  
    } else {
      $index=getIndex($loc) 
      $result[$index].'Count' = $result[$index].'Count' + $pcount
   }
}
```

but this code produces an output containing only one type and miscounted figures for the count. I attempted to refine the Function by modifying it to look like this:

```
Function getIndex($location)
{
  for($j = 0; $j -lt $result.Count; $j++) {
    if($result[$j].Location -contains "$location" -and $result[$j].'License Type' -contains "$item.licensetype") {
      $index=$j
      break;
    }
  }
  return $index
}
```

which results in my index operation failing due to the array index being evaluated to null. I feel like i'm missing something very simple here, but i can't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Group-Object and Measure-Object to accomplish what you wanted. First I group by Type, and assign a variable to the current type to be used later in a custom object. Then I group by Site, and for each site I get the sum of the counts, and output Type, Site, and that Sum as a custom object. I setup your test data as an array of objects just as you have them in your post. I named that `$Array`.

```
$array | group Type | %{
    $Type = $_.Name
    $_.group | group Site | %{
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Type=$Type
            Site=$_.Name
            Count=($_.Group|measure-object Count -sum).sum
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs exactly what you wanted:

```
Type   Site  Count
----   ----  -----
Copper Site1    17
Copper Site2    33
Bronze Site1    12
Bronze Site2    16
```

Comment: And on v4 and higher you can ditch the `$Type = $_.Name` and replace with `group Type -pv type | ... Site = $type.Name`.  Love me some PipelineVariable.  :-)

Comment: Well now that is awesome, I had no idea!

Comment: that worked perfectly!  @Keith Hill, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$counts = Import-CSV "C:\Users\Public\Scripts\counts.csv"

$counts | Sort-Object Site, Type -Unique | Select-Object Type, Site, @{Name = 'Count'; Expression = { $obj=$_;($counts | Where-Object {(($obj.Type -eq $_.Type) -and ($obj.Site -eq $_.Site))} | Measure-Object Count -Sum).Sum } }
```